# Django extend tab into tabular.html existing file

Tags: templates, django-templates, django-admin, extends

How do I extend/edit the `"admin/edit_inline/tabular.html"`?

I have this into my settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Metamanager/templates")],
        .....
    }
```

My `admin.TabularInLine`inside the admin.py:

```
class FileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UploadFile
    template = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Metamanager/templates/tabular.html")
```

and into my custom template:

```
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}

{% block table_content %}
<td class="original"><p>holaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p></td>

{%endblock%}
```

not showing the td into the body as I don't know what need to extend into the custom html exactly from tabular.html.

[image: where needs to put the customisation from the new html file.]

I want to make the link redirect to a view I have don for direct downloading

I need to extend the tabular.html auto created by Django bear in mind I don't have Forms at all, the screenshoot is a Django FileField rendered from models.py